# Best Practice to build websites for different screen size

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, layout, media-type

What is the best practice to build websites than can code with different screen sizes, for e.g. when resizing browser, or even when viewing a layout designed for desktop browser sizes such as 800X600 or more. I'm more a backend developer, now, I'm having to build a web application where I want to use jquery mobile. I just want that the layout changes for desktop as well. So far, I'm only aware of media types. Is there any better solution like a framework something. Thanks

Comment: Just google `responsive layout`. There are many frameworks that help you. [a](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/5-useful-css-tricks-for-responsive-design) [b](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design)

Comment: Oh yeah... and talking about frameworks, I use and prefer overall the rest Skeleton 1.2 (pure CSS). It's great and I've been using in all my projects with no issues. (www.getskeleton.com)

Comment: @Santz, can it be used with jquery mobile?

Comment: Of course. Actually, check my site, i'm using both: santz.net

Comment: nice one, good design! !!

Answer (score 1):

you can either use **client side** media-queries in css to specify the behavior

@media-query(min-width:320px) {
   .do_not_show_on_small { display:none}

}

[MDN Media Query Info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

or use the **server backend** and look at the user agent and send back different html...

http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/

Then the an example of server logic like this:

```
if (ff8) then
   send (browser_html.html)
else if (android os)
   sned (mobile_html.html)
```

(of course this could be different templates for the same data using a template engine).

Answer (score 1):

Need these on document's head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

And these are the standard Media Queries

```
/* #MEDIA QUERIES
================================================== */

/* Tablet Portrait size to standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
    body {min-width: 768px; } /* example */
}

/* All Mobile Sizes (devices and browser) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    body {min-width: 320px; } /* example */
}

/* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    body {min-width: 420px; } /* example */
}
```

Best of luck! Check my site to see how it works: www.santz.net